# Memory leak when using anonymous delegate with Loaded/Unloaded Event

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, user-controls

I have a WPF MainWindow that can change(navigate) UserControl inside a StackPanel:

```
// on code behind of MainWindow     
RootStackPanel.Children.Clear();

                UserControl1 uc1= new UserControl1();
                uc1.CustomizedEvent1+= EventHandler1;
                uc1.CustomizedEvent2+= EventHandler2;
                uc1.Loaded += (s, e1) =>
                 {
                        // Do something
                 };

                // Unsubscribe external event to prevent memory leak
                uc1.Unloaded += (s, e1) =>
                    {
                        uc1.CustomizedEvent1 -= EventHandler1;
                        uc1.CustomizedEvent2 -= EventHandler2;
                    };
RootStackPanel.Children.Add(uc1);

// same for UserControl 2,3,4....
```

Application will crashed after run for few hours so I added Unloaded event handler with anonymous delegate to prevent memory leak by unsubscribe all Event of UserControl. 
Will Unloaded with Anonymous Delegate cause memory leak? If yes, how to unsubscribe all event of UserControl without calling Unloaded?

I remember that internal event like as Loaded, Unloaded will be disposed by GC right?

And when dose anonymous delegate dispose?

Thanks all.

Comment: The CG will collect the User Control only if no other object is subscribed to the Unload event.

Comment: hi @PanagiotisLefas,
So my solution is bad because Unload's anonymous delegate still hold on MainWindow and GC can't collect UserControl.
Do you have any alternative solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: @QuocNguyen your solution is fine

Answer (score 0):

You said "Application will crashed after run for few hours so I added Unloaded event" - does that mean you change (add & remove) UserControld inside that StackPanel very very often? Futhermore each time you create a new UserControl you add those event handlers from MainWindow, right?

In such case you are doing all fine and assigning an anonymous delegate to Unloaded event which cleans up is the proper way to leave nice memory footprints.

Comment: Dont forget to mark an answer. If you have any other questions feel free to ask. Or open another thread.

Comment: **You said "Application will crashed after run for few hours so I added Unloaded event" - does that mean you change (add & remove) UserControld inside that StackPanel very very often? ** 
 
 Yes

**Futhermore each time you create a new UserControl you add those event handlers from MainWindow, right?**

Yes.

I think like you but i can't tell that when does Unloaded event dispose/unsubscribe? And user reported that my application was freeze after few hours working.

So do we have any alternative solution to unsubscribe all events of user control?

Comment: Unload of a UserControl happens when you call children.Remove(myUserControl). Set a breakpoint inside your anonymous method if you dont believe me. :) :)
In your case anonymous method doesnt hold any reference to other classes therefore it will be collected by gc once the complete UserControl gets thrown away. Which shall happen when you call children.Remove(..)

Comment: My teammate said that anonymous delegate is a static method and only be disposed when closed MainWindow.
Can you confirm this information?

Comment: Your teammate is wrong. Anonymous delegate is not a static method. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx E.g. create a anonymous delegate in a method and dont reference it from anywhere, when you exit the method scope delegate will be destroyed. You dont need to unsubscribe Unloaded since GC will collect everything at once in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to fix this issue:

- Use and EventHandler method instead of anonymous delegate.
- Call Unsubsribe in EventHandler method.

  ```
  .....
  // on code behind of MainWindow     
  RootStackPanel.Children.Clear();

          UserControl1 uc1= new UserControl1();
          uc1.CustomizedEvent1+= EventHandler1;
          uc1.CustomizedEvent2+= EventHandler2;               

          // Unsubscribe external event to prevent memory leak
          //uc1.Unloaded += (s, e1) =>
           //   {
           //       uc1.CustomizedEvent1 -= EventHandler1;
           //       uc1.CustomizedEvent2 -= EventHandler2;
           //   };
  RoutedEventHandler unloadedHandler = null;
  unloadedHandler = delegate(object s, RoutedEventArgs sev)
      {
   uc1.CustomizedEvent1 -= EventHandler1;
           uc1.CustomizedEvent2 -= EventHandler2;
  uc1.Unloaded -= unloadedHandler;
  };
      uc1.Unloaded += unloadedHandler;
  RootStackPanel.Children.Add(uc1);
  // same for UserControl 2,3,4....
  ```

Comment: Again you dont need to unsubscribe to Unloaded event. When UserControl gets removed from childrens list the GC will see that UserControl and your anonymous event handler are all alone lost in space and it will collect both at once.